# Suneditor insertHTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, suneditor

I'm trying to use the function: insertHTML

As per manual: editor.insertHTML('TEXTO DE TESTE', true, true);

I created a button and put a jquery

suneditor.insertHTML('Text 1', true, true);

But when clicking the button it does not add the text. But if I click on the editor and then click on the button, the text is added.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/github-markdown-css/3.0.1/github-markdown.min.css">
<link href="http://suneditor.com/dist/css/suneditor.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.49.0/lib/codemirror.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="text1">Text 1</button>
<button id="text2">Text 2</button>
<button id="text3">Text 3</button>



<textarea id="exampleOptions" style="width:100%; height:200px;">
Teste de Editor
</textarea>

<script src="http://suneditor.com/sample/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="http://suneditor.com/dist/suneditor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.49.0/lib/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.49.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.49.0/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/codemirror@5.49.0/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.11.1/dist/katex.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#text1").click( function(){
        suneditor.insertHTML('Text 1', true, true);
    }); 
    $("#text2").click( function(){
        suneditor.insertHTML('Text 3', true, true);
    }); 
    $("#text3").click( function(){
        suneditor.insertHTML('Text 2', true, true);
    }); 

    suneditor = SUNEDITOR.create('exampleOptions',{
        font : [
            'Arial',
            'tahoma',
            'Courier New,Courier'
        ],
        fontSize : [
            8, 10, 14, 18, 24, 36
        ],
        colorList: [
            ['#ccc', '#dedede', 'OrangeRed', 'Orange', 'RoyalBlue', 'SaddleBrown'],
            ['SlateGray', 'BurlyWood', 'DeepPink', 'FireBrick', 'Gold', 'SeaGreen']
        ],
        paragraphStyles: [
            'spaced',
            'neon',
            {
                name: 'Custom',
                class: '__se__customClass'
            }
        ],
        textStyles: [
            'translucent',
            {
                name: 'Emphasis',
                style: '-webkit-text-emphasis: filled;',
                tag: 'span'
            }
        ],
        width: '100%',
        maxWidth: '600px',
        minWidth: 400,
        height : 'auto',
        videoWidth : '80%',
        youtubeQuery : 'autoplay=1&mute=1&enablejsapi=1',
        imageWidth : 150,
        popupDisplay: 'local',
        resizingBar: false,
        buttonList : [
            [
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `insertHTML` is working with the last cursor position. So if you don't focus the editor, last position of cursor is `undefined` and `insertHTML` will not work until you focus the editor. By the way i believe there is `focus` method that you can focus the editor then use `insertHTML` method. [Documentation](http://suneditor.com/sample/html/out/document-editor.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.focus();
editor.insertHTML("...");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.